# Datadog - Is it possible to dedup the events sharing a specific identifier?

Tags: datadog

**Context:**

- I created in Datadog a new metric `payment_processed` with this tag:

  - `status` (failure or success)
- on top of this metric, I created what I call the `payment_failure_rate`

  - `(count(payment_processed.status=failure) / ( count(payment_processed.status=failure) + count(payment_processed.status=success) ))`
- I would like to monitor the `payment_failure_rate` with an anomaly detection algorithm

**Challenge:**

- On payment failure (ie; declined), it’s not unusual to see a user  re-trying (and failing) multiple time submitting the form
- With time, we found out (outside of Datadog) that deduplicating the events per customer before calculating the failure rate was a great way to make the metric more meaningful and useful
- For example, if 1 customer submit with success the form and an another customer submitted 5 times with failure the form

  - Then we found more useful to see the failure rate as 50% (1 failure / 2 attempt) vs 83.33% (5 failures / 6 attempts)
- I have not found a way to do the above in Datadog

**Question:** Is it possible in Datadog to dedup the events per customer before calculating the failure rate?